# VBA String without a space doesnt work, with a space does work

Tags: vba, excel

I am playing around with VBA in Excel, and cant for the life of me figure out why this error is popping up.

The following code works:

```
Cells(1, 1) = " =if(counta( " & aLoc & "Subbies'!$A$2:$A$20>0 ""YES"", ""NO"" "
```

The following code doesnt work:

```
Cells(1, 1) = "=if(counta( " & aLoc & "Subbies'!$A$2:$A$20>0 ""YES"", ""NO"" "
```

So Just by removing the space to make the line of code insert a formula rather than a string causes the compiler to through up error 1004.

In other lines ive used itll insert a formula no problem, but concatenating text with a local variable seems to throw this up. Any ideas?

Comment: It is because the formula is not complete.  You are missing all your `)` and so excel cannot put it in as it is a bad formula.

Comment: I dont really care if the formula works at the moment (im just messing around at the moment) but the error isnt within excel, its within the code, ie the compiler wont allow the string to be inserted, even though its wrong. It should be an excel error, not a VBA error

Comment: I should clarify; the formula was complete when I started it all, and then started removing things to see if it was those characters throwing up the error, until I found it was the = sign touching the " without a space.

Comment: That is correct the compiler will not allow a formula that is incorrect to be entered.  If you tried to enter this directly into excel an error would occur vba is throwing that error.

Comment: `Cells(1, 1) = "=if(counta('" & aLoc & "Subbies'!$A$2:$A$20)>0, ""YES"", ""NO"" )"`

Comment: Is that correct? I thought the compiler would insert whatever I wanted (its just a string at the end of the day) and then it would be up to excel to tell me its wrong

Comment: the leading space would have excel consider the cell content as a text and prevent it from considering subsequent text as a formula even if preceded by `=`

Comment: Excel ***is*** telling it is wrong, The error is being passed to vba and vba is passing it in the form of the error 1004.  get the formula to work in excel then replace the variables with the concatenation and all the `"` with `""`.  My guess is that you were missing something.  I figure it was the `'` at the beginning of the sheet name.

Comment: Yes but I get the error in the VBA code rather than in Excel. it should insert whatever I want it to, and then if there is a gap Excel will treat it as a string, and if theres no gap itll treat it as a formula. Ive tried scotts alteration (which brings it back to the original formula I had before I started deleting stuff) and its still throwing an error

Comment: the ' at the beginning is in the variable aLoc

Comment: As with excel saying its wrong it should allow it to go in and the excel error dialogue box should pop up ( or N/A or #ref or whatever the issue may be) rather than the code stopping halfway through the run?

Comment: Nope, that is not how it works,  If the formula is bad and excel will not see it as a formula it throws an error.  PUt your string n a variable first `t="=if(counta('" & aLoc & "Subbies'!$A$2:$A$20)>0, ""YES"", ""NO"" )"` then `Debug.Print t` to see if it is exactly like you would expect it to be.

Comment: Cells(1, 1) = "=if(b2>b1, ""YES"" , ""NO"")" works fine!

Comment: Scott, put a small summary of not being able to put any old incorrect formula into a cell using VBA and youll get a green tick from me. Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel will not allow an incorrect formula to be entered.

When putting a formula directly in the sheet you get the an error if it is not a correct formula and the cell remains in edit mode till either deleted or fixed.

The 1004 error is just vba representing that error.

To help find the error in the formula, place your string in a variable then debug.print it to see what is not correct:

```
t = "=if(counta('" & aLoc & "Subbies'!$A$2:$A$20)>0, ""YES"", ""NO"" )"
Debug.Print t
```

This will put the formula in the immediate window as it would in excel, allowing the developer to check to see if there is an error.

Bottom line:

You can put a string of what ever you want in a cell, but if you are trying to put a formula it must be complete and accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is complaining that you are trying to put a bad formula in a cell.  If you want to put a "formula as text" in a cell, then:

```
Sub DontQuoteMe()
    Cells(1, 1) = "'=if(counta( " & aLoc & "Subbies'!$A$2:$A$20>0 ""YES"", ""NO"" "
End Sub
```

[image]

*(using the space accomplishes the same thing)*